# Why does MIT Kerberos kinit warn "Your passwod will expire" when your principal is what is about to expire?

Tags: kerberos, mitkerberos

While doing some experimenting I noticed that the MIT Kerberos version 5 "kinit" program will warn you when either your password is about to expire (within 7 days) or when your principal is about to expire.  However, the warning message is identical in both cases.  Is this for some security reason or is this a bug?  When a principal expires kinit no longer allows you to obtain a TGT (You get the message: "kinit: Client's entry in database has expired while getting initial credentials").  In contrast, once your password expires kinit will prompt you for a new one.

Comment: I can't think of any security related reason not to print the exact cause.